# High throughput summary tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very high throughput production web application that I need to design effective SQL summary tables for. For each request going through the application I need to append 4 or 5 values, to hourly or daily stats in the DB

Three options I thought of:

1. Basic summary table with cols such as "day", "totalA", "totalB", "totalC"

I know from experience that the throughput of the application in production is high enough that any attempt to constantly update a single row will cause huge wait locks and stall all the threads

Also this means I always have to do a query like "UPDATE WHERE today .. ROWS EFFECTED == 0 ? INSERT..." which seems like a bad pattern

2. Table with 1 row per application request with cols such as "day", "amountA", amountB", "amountC"

Due to the super high throughput this table would get at least a few million rows added per day. As I would need to keep this data forever the table size would some become a real problem

3. Option 2 + job to summarise data in another table

Let's say I set a job to sum up data from the option 2 table, then insert into a separate summary table, then delete from option 2 table

The problem I think with this solution would be that during the DELETE process, the table would lock and cause INSERT delays in the application which is unfortunately not acceptable even for a period of a few seconds

I'm actually at a loss as to the best practice in this scenario, any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I prefer option 3 with an improvement: you could use two tables (or one table with partitioning) for staging. You save your data in table A in even days, and inside table B in odd days. The day after you can consolidate the data of the previous day without incurring in any concurrent operation. The same logic works even with higher granularity. The idea of even and odd should take in consideration the datediff(d, {D'1900-01-01'}, GetDate()) to avoid the problem of  31st-1st. Since you get rid of an entire staging table, you can use "truncate".

Comment: Could you add a bit more of information about your use case ? like is the insert linear or can you run job with lock at line ? when do you need the summary ? what kind of data do you have (I see a date, so you can partition by date at least)